# Take one month back in teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I  have some tables (samples are brought here) like this

scores (the score is calculated once in each month for each branch_cust in the 28 for specific month)

```
Branch_cust model_date score 
1            28/12/2013  4
1            28/01/2014  3
1            28/02/2014  2
1            28/03/2014  7
1            28/04/2014  3
1            28/05/2014  5
1            28/06/2014  6
2            28/12/2013  9
2            28/01/2014  10
2            28/02/2014  12
2            28/03/2014  11
2            28/04/2014  10
2            28/05/2014  7
2            28/06/2014  8
```

loans:

```
Branch_cust agreement_date 
1              05-01-2014        
1              29-01-2014        
2              27-02-2014         
2              28-02-2014
```

Loans:

desired output:

```
Branch_cust agreement_date loan_open_score
1              05-01-2014        4
1              29-01-2014        3
2              27-02-2014        10  
2              28-02-2014        12
```

Logic to create the loan_open_score :

If the day in the month of the agreement_date is less then "28" then bring the score of the month previous to the month of the agreement date.
If the day is greater or equal to "28" then bring the score for the month equal to the month of the agreement date.

Example: In the sample data for branch_cust = 1 the agreement_date was 05-01-2014 - meaning - day = 5 so I need to go back to  Dec 2013 and take the score from there.

Any help how to do this? thank's. I was thinking of "join" and then substract 1 in "case of.." but I don't know how to handle the case when the date is 'dd-01-YYYY' in sql-teradata.

updated : column data type of the dates are dates.

Comment: Column data types? (model_date and agreement_date)

Comment: the column data types are dates.

Answer (score 0):

`trunc(agreement_date,'mon') + 27` returns the 28th of the current month. Now you can apply some logic and join on this calculated date:

```
case when            trunc(agreement_date,'mon') + 27 > agreement_date
     then add_months(trunc(agreement_date,'mon') + 27,-1)
     else            trunc(agreement_date,'mon') + 27
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to get the latest model_date per agreement date and join it to the scores table. This way you don't have to manipulate dates.

```
select t.branch_cust,t.agreement_Date,s.score
from scores s
join (select distinct l.branch_cust,l.agreement_Date
      ,max(s.model_Date) over(partition by l.branch_cust,l.agreement_Date) as max_model_Date
      from scores s
      join loans l on s.branch_cust=l.branch_cust and l.agreement_Date >= s.model_Date
      ) t 
on s.branch_cust=t.branch_cust and s.model_Date=t.max_model_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *

from            scores  as s
        join    loans   as l

        on      l.Branch_cust   =
                s.Branch_cust

            and l.model_date    =
                add_months 
                (
                    trunc(S.agreement_date,'mm')+27
                   ,case when extract(day from s.agreement_date) < 28 then -1 else 0 end
                )
```